# Questions about ありたい

Tags: words

> 心がいつも美しくありたいです
>
> I want my heart to always be beautiful.
>
> 心がいつも美しくして欲しいです (Incorrect)
>
> 心がいつも美しくなりたいです
>
> I want my heart to always be beautiful.(?)

My Japanese friend wrote the first sentence, while I wrote it over attempting to use 欲しい instead. I am unfamiliar with this use of ある, and have a few questions about it.

Is it derived from the same "existence" verb, ある -- 在る ?

My other question is how personal is the nuance when expressing a wish or desire, compared to 欲しい? If the second version that I wrote with 欲しい is acceptable, how do the two sentences differ in tone, politeness, meaning and expression?

I am wondering if ありたい expresses a more, or less personal desire than 欲しい.

Furthermore, can one rewrite the original sentence using another verb, while retaining the same meaning? 
Lastly, is my translation correct? Or should it read "I want my heart to always be beautiful."? I had thought that the original sentence corresponded to something like "I always want the person on the inside to be beautiful (just like how I am on the outside)," but maybe I am wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: FYI, if you're going to write `ある` with kanji, `有る` is usually for "have"/"possess"; Existence is `在る`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `たい` is used when the expected change is on the subject or it is about the subject's action.

> お菓子を食べたい
>   'I want to eat some/the snack.'

- `ほしい` is used when it is about something other than the subject.

> お菓子を食べてほしい
>   'I want someone to eat some/the snack.'

Your second sentence is ungrammatical because `心` is the object. It should be:

> 心をいつも美しくして欲しいです

But this sentence cannot be interpreted as describing your own mind. It has to mean the mind of someone else. The same thing can be said about your third sentence.

A possible rewrite of the first example is:

> 心がいつも美しくなりたいです

Comment: `ほしい` can still be used about oneself; for example: アイスが欲しい.

Comment: ありがとう。　On the last sentence you suggested, 心がいつも美しくなりたいです, could this be interpreted as, "I always want to become beautiful inside" as opposed to "be beautiful inside"? Which  interpretation is more correct?

Comment: @summea That is the main predicate usage of `欲しい`, which is different from the auxiliary `ほしい` that comes after `て`.

Comment: @yadokari I am not sure about your question, but do you mean the scope of `いつも`, that is: "always [want to become beautiful]" vs. "want to [always become beautiful]"? If so, then it can only mean the latter.

Comment: @sawa I mean the difference between "be beautiful" as opposed to "become beautiful". Which meaning do you think comes closer when interpreting 美しくなりたいです?

Comment: @yadokari Now I see what you mean. Since it is unnatural to consider continuously becoming beautiful (becoming more beautiful each moment than before), it has to mean "be beautiful". In fact, `いつも` has to take even a narrower scope : "become [always beautiful]" or "come to be in the situation of always being beautiful".

Comment: Oh. i think i was mistakenly interpreting it as, "I always want my heart to be beautiful" but I guess it should be interpreted as "I want my heart to always be beautiful."? So actually, is my original english translation wrong? Should it read instead, " I want the person inside to always be beautiful. / I want to be forever beautiful inside"?  what would be the most literal (and unnatural if need be) english translation of the original sentence?

Comment: @yadokari Yes. Your new translation is right.

Comment: @sawa. I have a slight point of confusion regarding "But this sentence cannot be interpreted as describing your own mind". If ほしい is used in `心をいつも美しくしてほしいです`, it is for oneself isn't it? For the second or third person ほしがる or ほしがっている would be used?

Comment: @Flaw You need to be careful with what is the subject and what is the object (or the subject of the embedded part). In `心をいつも美しくしてほしい`, the first person wishes about the second/third person's mind. With `がる`, the second/third person makes a wish about something.

Answer (score 1):

I hear ありたい used when it is more of a long term desire:

> i.e. "I want to be a kind person."

I hear ほしい used when it is more of a short term desire:

> i.e. "I want an ice cream cone."

Edit:

As far as your question goes about how the two sentences differ, I still think that you'd want to use ありたい for something that is more of a long term desire (i.e. something one wants to become.)  Otherwise, it sounds (to me, at least,) that you only want to be beautiful on the inside... but just for the moment.

Edit Two:

For double-checking your translation, we could try breaking up the sentence like this:

> 心がいつも美しくありたいです ↓ 
>   ありたいです (want to be)
>   美しくありたいです (want to be beautiful)
>   いつも美しくありたいです (want to be always beautiful)
>   心がいつも美しくありたいです (Would that my heart be always beautiful.)

Comment: Thank you.
If this second sentence is correct, do they mean the same thing? How do they differ?
心がいつも美しくありたいです

I always want to be beautiful on the inside.

心がいつも美しくして欲しいです

I always want to be beautiful on the inside.

Comment: Edited answer to hopefully address your question about how those particular sentences differ.

Comment: This is how the original writer interpreted it: I want to be beautiful in my heart.(her english is not fluent) Are you suggesting it has the feel of a poetic phrase? or is it just hard to translate? would this be a statement used in everyday convo? or does it sound as rarefied as your last translation? thanks 4 yr input btw.

Comment: @yadokari It doesn't seem like something that would be used in everyday conversation (but then again, people can say anything...!) It sounds more like something someone would say about their outlook on life or about their personal philosophy, etc.  My final translation (at the end of the answer,) has more of a poetic (vs everyday usage,) feel to it... with the "would that" part.  I think that with a phrase like this... you would want to make sure it has some sort of poetic (or quotable,) feel to it.  You don't need to have that exact poetic-type of wording for it... but it might seem fitting~!

Comment: Under your intended interpretation, the steps you provide are wrong. if the object of `たい` "want" is "always be beautiful", then the steps are `あり` → ... → `いつも美しくあり` → ... → `いつも美しくありたいです`.

Comment: @sawa not sure I follow what you are saying.

Comment: @summea I am saying that there is no such things as `ありたいです` and `美しくありたいです`, given the interpretation.

Comment: @sawa ありたいです = want to be

Comment: I think one problem is the fact that 美しい is an adjective. In order to form the negative form, you first transform 美しい to x 美しくある, then transform ある to ない (美しくない). Similarly, to form the desiderative of 美しい, you have to first transform 美しい to x 美しくある, then transform ある to ありたい (美しくありたい). A similar process occurs with the use of は (that is, 美しい - x 美しくある - 美しくはある). I've marked the intermediate state of 美しくある with an 'x' as it doesn't normally occur in Japanese.

Comment: Another possible rendition of the intended meaning, with a different nuance, is いつも心が美しいままでいたい.

Comment: @Bathrobe Hmm... but what if the heart isn't beautiful to begin with, in that case?  Using まま implies that it is already beautiful.