# What does [可愛が]りたい mean and how to use it?

Tags: grammar

桃香を可愛がりたい気持ち、抑えられないよ

Touka o kawaii ga ritai kimochi, osae rare nai yo.

The example sentence is like that. I'm wondering if this ritai here is in the same use as aritai like in [Questions about ありたい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4848/questions-about-%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84).

What I know is that 可愛 means cute and since を is a direct object particle, it makes

```
Touka is cute
```

気持ち is feelings

抑えられ is suppressed, and ない negates it, so it means cannot be suppressed, but the りたい part makes me wonder.

If the use of りたい here is the same as in that link above, then does it means the English translation would be

```
It can't be suppressed that I felt Touka is getting more and more cuter
```

?

Comment: It's not りたい it's 可愛【かわい】がる　→　連用形　+　～たい.
(someone) can't resist fawning over Momoka.

Comment: Where did the extra "i" come from at the end of "kawaii"?  Perhaps you need to get away from romaji, use kanji hiragana - it is quite easy with a modern keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

かわいがる comes from かわいい　+　がる, but is almost a word in its own right.
形容詞　→　語幹　+　がる = feel like / act like 形容詞
寒がる・暑がる・偉がる　…

かわいがりたい comes from かわいがる　+　たい
動詞　→　連用形　+　たい = want (to do)
したい・行きたい・帰りたい　…

```
気持ちを抑える
control one's feelings

気持ちを/が抑えられない
unable to control one's feelings

桃香を可愛がりたい
want to fawn over Momoka

⇒　(Someone) can't resist the desire to fawn over Momoka.
```

Comment: So がる usually means feel or act like in most words, but in かわいがる it loses this independent meaning, and just means "to fawn over"?